# How to use angular project as dependency

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 10 project (Project A) and I would like to know if it's possible to extend it in another Angular project (Project B) installing it as a dependency.

I know that I can create a Project A library and install it in Project B, but I am not sure about extend it and add new funcionality from this Project A.

To sum up, I want to know if it is possible to to extend an Angular project in other Angular project without ducplicate code.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  I mean, if i understand the question correctly, it's effectively the same thing.  If Project A has components, services, etc, that you want to extend in Project B, you would install Project A and create components that extend whatever you're wanting to extend in B.  Just make sure, if both projects are in the same angular workspace, to setup the paths definition in your tsconfig correctly.

Comment: But what aboud the views? Ok, i can extend services, components and anything else, add methods and features but how can you edit the views with this approach?

Comment: @CSantos a view/template is part of a component. Component inheritance is the same whether you're extending a local component in the same project or you're extending a component in another project.  In both cases, the template of the extending component is what's used.  You're able to share the behaviors of the base component, but it's the extending component's template that's used.  That's the same regardless of whether in separate project or not.

Comment: I think i'm not understand you. I'd really apreciate a simple example of how to add new features from an angular library

Comment: @CSantos  Sure.  So, like i said, component inheritance is the same, whether you're extending a component in a library or extending a component locally.  It's the same principle.  This is a simple example, where one component extends another, and uses the Input property from the base class in the template of the extending component.  So any public or protected methods or properties in the base class are available.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nldqv1

Comment: Thank you so much for the example, but it's not exactly the thing that i meant. How do you edit the template of the hello component from the doogby component?? Because if im extending a library I can't edit the template of a component. So how would you add a button inside of a hello component from the goodby component? This button has to only appear in the goodby component.

Comment: @CSantos That's not really possible.  Component inheritance just allows you to extend the component class, but the child has its own template.  You could try doing something with content projection, where you use an ng-content in the child component template, and nest the parent component under the child.